# Assistance improving a Phone Number Extension parsing query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that seems to work, but it strikes me as unnecessarily wordy (good for understanding, but may not be good for speed).  I'm hoping someone can code-golf this into something more functional.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      strng varchar(5000)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (strng)
VALUES 
    ('555-444-6285'),
    ('intercom 5362'),
    ('555-444-6285 ext. 5362'),
    ('(306) 250-4968'),
    ('011-555-888 9965-6859'),
    ('Not a Phone Number')

SELECT LeftNumeric
        , CASE WHEN PosOfNum > 1 THEN LEFT(RightRemainder, PosOfNum-1) ELSE RightRemainder END AS MiddleAlpha
        , CASE WHEN PosOfNum > 1 THEN RIGHT(RightRemainder, LEN(RightRemainder)-PosOfNum+1) ELSE '' END AS RightNumeric
FROM
(
SELECT strng
        , LeftNumeric
        , RightRemainder
        , PATINDEX('%[-0-9()]%', RightRemainder) as PosOfNum
FROM
(
SELECT strng 
        ,PosOfChar
        , CASE WHEN PosOfChar > 0 THEN LEFT(strng, PosOfChar-1) ELSE Strng END AS LeftNumeric
        , CASE WHEN PosOfChar > 0 THEN RIGHT(strng, LEN(strng)-PosOfChar+1) ELSE '' END AS RightRemainder
FROM
(
SELECT strng
        , PATINDEX('%[^-0-9.() ]%', strng) as PosOfChar
    FROM @Temp
) Process1
) Process2
) Process3
```

The net result of running the above will be as follows:

```
LeftNumeric             MiddleAlpha         RightNumeric
555-444-6285        
                        intercom            5362
555-444-6285            ext.                5362
(306) 250-4968      
011-555-888 9965-6859       
                        Not a Phone Number
```

Comment: The indentation is lousy but the query looks quite reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution we went with, and it works quite well.